# Analyzing Joe Hisaishi's "Neko Bus"

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

(Original Song)

[image]

[image]

What is this 4# note that keep appearing in the left hand part?
If you see picture 1 , the beginning of [A] part.
There is D# in the left hand (4#).
 Also in the Picture 2 , The E chord ,
there is also the A# (4#)

what is happening here?

Comment: OK so why does this question get voted up and answered when [my other question about a specific song](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69591/what-is-time-signature-of-sarumans-theme-from-lotr) gets closed for asking details of a specific song? @richard

Comment: @richard "Questions about transcribing or finding a particular song, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers."

Comment: @S.Imp It's a fair question. You may consider bringing it up on [our Meta site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

In both instances, it's just a chromatic lower neighbor tone. In the first case it's ♯4 to 5, in the second case it's ♯1 to 2. (But note that the latter instance is decorating the *chordal* fifth; the composer has just transposed this little vamp to fit with the V chord.)

It's a really common actions; it doesn't suggest a move to another key, it just adds some flavor to an otherwise diatonic environment.

In fact, it's so common that it's actually happening elsewhere in the piece: whenever you have these `Adim` chords that resolve to `A`, check out the upper-most voice: the E♭ to E♮ is the exact same pitch progression as D♯ to E!

Comment: Does it got something to do with the lydian mode ? Or the blue note ? Because the whole song gives me some kind of blues feel

Comment: No, it's just a decoration.   If you try to analyse EVERY note in terms of functional harmony you'll go mad!

Comment: Didn't a certain Ludwig van do something similar Fur Elise?